# how to apply standard and advanced theme to tinymce in drupal 7

Tags: wysiwyg

I have integrated wysiwyg with tinymce editor.. now Tinymce asks to choose buttons which we want in editor... I want to apply its own theme like 'standard' or 'advanced' or any other and dont want to select buttons.. 
How can I do it ?[image: Here in image, I have two options like 'full_html' and 'standard'.. I want to configure tinymce accrding their names.. standard theme for 'standard' option and 'advanced' theme for 'full_html'..]